# updating user review in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i was wondering if there was a way a user can update a review they have already written, i tried using cancan but ran into a few problems so i rather find out if there is an easier way. This is code from the 'new' method in the reviews controller

```
def new
  if logged_in?
    @review = Review.new(:film_id => params[:id], :name =>
      User.find(session[:user_id]).name)

    session[:return_to] = nil
  else 
    session[:return_to] = request.url
    redirect_to login_path, alert: "You must be logged in to write a review"
  end
end
```

and the 'create' method

```
def create
  # use the class method 'new' with the parameter 'review', populated 
  # with values from a form 
  @review = Review.new(params[:review])
  # attempt to save to the database, the new review instance variable 
  if @review.save
    # use the class method 'find' with the id of the product of the 
    # saved review and assign this product object to the variable 'product'
    film = Film.find(@review.film.id)
    # redirect the reviewer to the show page of the product they reviewed,
    # using the product variable, and send a notice indicating the review 
    # was successfully added
    redirect_to film, notice: "Your review was successfully added"
  else
    # if the review could not be saved, return / render the new form
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

i want the user to edit their review if they have already written a review for a product. Instead of having two reviews from the same user for the same product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially sub something like this into the `create` method:

```
# Assumes that your user names are unique
@review = Review.find_or_create_by_film_id_and_name(params[:review][:film_id], User.find(session[:user_id]).name)
@review.update_attributes(params[:review])
```

This does the following

1. Checks whether the user has created a review for the film
2. If yes, assigns the existing review to the `@review` instance variable
3. If not, creates a new `Review` object and assigns it to `@review`
4. Updates `@review` with `params[:review]`

Alternatively, the following statements will accomplish the same without using the Rails `find_or_create` convenience method:

```
user_name = User.find(session[:user_id]).name # To avoid two DB lookups below
@review = Review.find_by_film_id_and_name(params[:review][:film_id],  user_name) || Review.new(:film_id => params[:review][:film_id], :name => user_name)
@review.update_attributes(params[:review])
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a record, you should use the `update` action, which is requested after the user submitted the `edit` form.

Comment: currently the user can write many reviews for the same product what i ideally want is the ability to recognize if the user has written a review for a product if so than forward them to the edit_path for that review rather than the option to write a new review for the same product.

Answer (score 0):

Make your User model have has_many/has_one :reviews. And Review model belongs_to :user. And then if you have any kind of authorization(and you should have, for ex: devise) you'll know if user of review is currently logged user. If so then render edit button, otherwise not render.

Also according to CRUD conventions, there are 2 actions you need. First its `edit` and other one `update`. You can read about it on railsguides.com